# Laravel validation - array of object always pass

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to validate array of object in Laravel. The request that I am trying to validate are as follows:

```
[
    "email" => null
    "date" => "2020-07-04"
    "components" => [
        0 => {
          "id": 1
          "name": "Valve"
          "model": ""
        }
        1 => {
          "id": 2
          "name": "Actuator"
          "model": "Hello World"
          "manufacturer": "wer"
        }
    ]
    "note" => null
]
```

Specifically having issue with `components` part. According to many other resources, my validation rules writes as this:

```
$rules = [
    'email' => ['required', 'exists:customers,email', 'email:rfc,dns'],
    'date' => ['required', 'date'],
    'reference' => ['required'],
    'components' => ['array', 'min:1'],
    'components.*.model' => ['required', 'string'],
    'components.*.quantity' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1'],
    'components.*.manufacturer' => ['required', 'string']
];
```

And this rules are not rejecting my example post in terms of `components` array. I would expected each `component` will have a `model`, `quantity` and `manufacturer` so I expected this validation would not passed. But this doesn't work. Any thought?

Comment: [I tested your rules as shown here](https://gist.github.com/matticustard/4486dbc4cb0a1199151fd3877baf78ef) and they work as expected.  Please add the code that demonstrates how your rules are being applied and how the validation is being performed.

Comment: Yes, please pass a dd() of the data being validated where the rules are not working.